# magento catalogsearch search for all products (like a view all brands page )

Tags: magento

For a project I need to make a kind of view all manufactures page, I am hoping to use catalogsearch but without any parameters. What I mean is the normal catalogsearch is ran and all shoes in all manufacture categories are returned.

The url that is normally passed is testshop.com//catalogsearch/result/index/?manufacturer=2522&q=shoe%20manufactures this works but when I try to pass testshop.com//catalogsearch/result/index/? (or along those lines) this does not work.

I have not started coding this yet as I am not sure where to begin so need a point in the right direction.

I am thinking of just finding the default category id and using this, but not sure if this is the best option to use.

Any advice or help will be great as always. Will post my finished code on here once complete as I think with magento help can be a bit limited.

Cheers

Jason

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try getting the search Model pragmatically

Here is the code to get the Search model:

```
$search = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced');
```

To actually search put in the following:

```
$search = Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced')->addFilters(array('name' => $term));
```

Then to get the results in an object, enter the following line:

```
$search->getProductCollection();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I did it. It was a bit of a hack but works perfectly.

I noticed that if you make a search and remove all the filters you are left with a GET request that look something like this /catalogsearch/result/index/?q=Shoe+Brand . But the filters where not showing on the left hand side as a normal catalogsearch would.

So I found the default category id and added this to the GET request. The GET request now looked like this /catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=2&q=Shoe+Brand .

Although the GET request included q=Shoe+Brand it was not actually using this as search criteria.

This was now returning a catalogsearch page with the default category as a filter.

This was showing default category in the filter and breadcrumbs so I had to change the appropriate phtml files to check for this and display 'all brands' instead of 'default category'.

Hope this helps someone else

Jason